# Why do questions pop up on the Home Page, then are voluntarily removed by their authors?

Tags: discussion

Why do I keep seeing a bunch of questions popping up on the Home Page, then being voluntarily removed by their authors? I'm sure I've seen it at least twice now, where I've been on a new question, writing an answer, and BOOM! Suddenly, it's deleted! It's not even one of those junk questions that I'd expect to be closed or anything! And I never see it again... Does anyone know why this happens? (I think it was different users, but I might be mistaken...)

Is this intentional? Is it a bug? Is there a reason why a user would do this that I didn't think of?

*Note: I'm not upset, I'm just curious. It just seems weird to me that that would occur, and also if it is a bug, then I guess Meta can thank me later :)*

Here's the links, though I'm not sure what good they'll do: [1st time](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82431/notes-associated-with-trumpet#82431), [2nd time](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/how-do-you-read-notes-above-the-staff).

Comment: It might help if you provide the link to those questions (perhaps from your browser history). I believe 99.9% it's not a bug, but *possibly* a user circumventing the ban and get caught by mods.

Comment: @AndrewT. Found two of the times it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen people do this for a few reasons.

Sometimes it is to avoid down votes - posters don't realise that deleting questions can impact their ability to post more than down votes can...

Sometimes someone answers and the OP realises they asked a simple question, or maybe think as they have been answered there is no reason to keep the question.

But it could be anything.

In this case, I have undeleted the first one, as it had a valid answer. The second one is also a reasonable question, but it has no answers so self deletion does not impact anyone.